# javascript aviod splitting sub string

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, split

Im working on Javascript and my string contains

`"delhi,bangalore,pune,otherCities(chennai,mumbai)"`

and Im trying to split the array. This works fine for me by `arr.split(",")`

```
 ["delhi", "bangalore", "pune", "otherCities(chennai", "mumbai)"]
```

but when we carefully observe **otherCities** has contains 2 values, this also is split into 2 different values. which is not expected

My expected output `["delhi", "bangalore", "pune", "otherCities(chennai, mumbai)"]`.

Im not sure how to achieve this. Is there any other way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex split

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/u41JzM/1)**

```js
let str = "delhi,bangalore,pune,otherCities(chennai,mumbai)"

console.log(str.split(/,(?![^\(]*[\)])/))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Regex. Eg:

```js
const cities = "delhi,bangalore,pune,otherCities(chennai,mumbai)";
const citiesSplitted = cities.split(/,(?![^()]*\))/);
console.log(citiesSplitted);
```

Comment: @spidy If one of the answers is correct and worked for you, please mark it as correct and accepted answer. This way other users can move on to other questions instead of spending time on questions which have already been answered.